# A error has been detected by the JRE

Tags: java, runtime, environment

This is my first topic. At the beginning i would like to say that i do not know if the code is correct. This code was first in my GUI programing but this is not a problem. When i try to run the code error appears. Did anyone have the same problem. Thx for help. Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public Main(){
        setSize(300,200);
        setTitle("My Title");
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Main frame = new Main();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Error:

```
> #
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fff52cdfd0c, pid=6244, tid=0x0000000000000e08
> #
> # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
> # Problematic frame:
> # C  [d3d9.dll+0xfd0c]
> #
> # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
> #
> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
> # D:\EclipseWorkSpace\GUI8_LW_S15300\hs_err_pid6244.log
> #
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
> #
```

I download the newest Java version.
I checked Windows updates and hardware drivers.

Comment: Try to work with a tutorial on this problem, and use a debugger to check what the issue is. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: Sounds to be a general problem in Windows: https://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml

Comment: Are you using any Eclipse IDE? I yes then please delete workspace and create a new one.
Hope this will help.